# open two new windows/tabs (different external sites) from a single button press in c#

Tags: javascript, c#

Is there a way I can open two pages, both in external websites, from a single button press in c# (or jquery/javascript, having set the parameters via c#)?

The context is I am trying to allow users to share content to both twitter and facebook with a single click.

When my user performs an action on my site, they generate (in the c# code-behind) a custom url. this needs to be passed to twitter and the fb share dialog via c#.

I'm able to build the 2 urls I need using String.Format to pass my custom url and other information, but at the moment the user needs to press one button for FB, and one for Twitter - I'd love to get that down to a single button press.

Comment: One click - one window... There is very good chance that even if you get code correct only one window will open as  browsers generally try to protect users from porn site's behavior or opening multiple windows.

Answer (score 0):

On the button press event can you just load both?

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('" + url1+ "','_blank')", true);

 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('" + url2+ "','_blank')", true);
```

Comment: i don't know if it was browser settings or what but i'd tried  this approach and before posting here it didn't work. I have found what i think is a problem to this specific solution. facebook share dialog demands a redirect uri. so i created a page specifically to be redirected to from facebook including a parameter needed to identify what to send to twitter. this is picked up in page load, so the user is therefore taken directly from the facebook share dialog to the facebook tweet dialog. i thnk this will serve my purpose.

Comment: I just tried this using a windows form and process.start:
     `ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://www.facebook.com/");
            Process.Start(sInfo);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ProcessStartInfo sInfo2 = new ProcessStartInfo("http://www.twitter.com/");
            Process.Start(sInfo2);`

You should be able to substitute with a registerstartupscript using javascript.  The key here is the let the application sleep for one second between the calls to IE.